# Picocom command no longer works after detach

Tags: raspberry-pi, uart, picocom

I am attempting to log UART data from my USB port to an output file.  The following command works.

```
picocom /dev/ttyUSB0 -b 115200 | ts '[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]' >> ~/output.log
```

However, once I attempt to detach from this process,

```
picocom /dev/ttyUSB0 -b 115200 | ts '[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]' >> ~/output.log &
```

the command no longer works.

How can I detach from this process and let my logger run in the background?

Comment: with the first command, I can open another terminal and watch the logs append to the logfile with tail -f.  If I detach with the second command, no logs make it to the output file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like [tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki), [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/), or [dtach](https://dtach.sourceforge.net/). For example, using `dtach`:

```
dtach -n /tmp/serial sh -c 'picocom -b 115200 /dev/ttyUSB0 > output.log'
```

This will start `picocom` detached from the terminal; it will happily continue running until you re-attach to it and exit:

```
dtach -a /tmp/serial
```

---

You can do the same thing with `tmux`:

```
tmux new-session -s serial -d 'picocom -b 115200 /dev/ttyUSB0 > output.log'
```

You can then re-attach to that session...

```
tmux attach -t serial
```

...and exit `picocom`.